# No OpenID endpoint found using DotNetOpenAuth and Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, dotnetopenauth, html5boilerplate

I am currently trying to migrate an ASP.NET MVC 3 Website to Windows Azure (As a Website).

The site uses DotNetOpenAuth 4.0. I have no issue authenticating when testing from my computer, however in Azure I get the following error:

"No OpenID endpoint found"

I try to authenticate using my Google account using the following ID: "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"

Does anyone have a suggestion? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There could variety of issues as I can quite a few here:

First thing to cover is that if you're running behind proxy please Specify the following:

```
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">  
  <proxy autoDetect="True" usesystemdefault="True"/>  
</defaultProxy>
```

You can also add little Request.Form["openid_identifier"] in your code to verify if that is  returning a valid URL (Openid path to Google).

Sometime, when testing applications to locally some of the local settings are stick in web.config, and cause problem when uploading the same. Please verify your web.config for all correct cloud based URL and settings.